# How to make vim cursor to be in central line always?

Tags: vim

I want to make my vim to behave in such a way as after each command there is a trailing `zz` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scrolloff` (`so`)
option is documented like this in Vim ([:help 'scrolloff'](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27scrolloff%27), with my emphasis below):

> Minimal number of screen lines to keep above and below the cursor.
> This will make some context visible around where you are working.  **If
> you set it to a very large value (999) the cursor line will always be
> in the middle of the window** (except at the start or end of the file or
> when long lines wrap).

So doing the following may do what you want:

```
:set so=999
```

When the end of the editor's buffer is visible, having `so` set to 999 does not have *exactly* the same effect as using `zz`.